# Error on simple script to open new tab

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to run a simple script which simply opens a new tab, but am getting
 `execution error: An error of type -10810 has occurred. (-10810)`
I am running on Yosemite.

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
    delay 2 
end tell
```

Comment: Is accessibility enabled for the  Terminal/AppleScript in the Security preferences ?

Comment: "System Events" is checked in the 'Accessibility" section of "Privacy" if this is what you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    if not (exists window 1) then
        reopen
    else
        do script ""
    end if
end tell
```